# FluentValidation custom validator with dependent rules

Tags: c#, validation, fluentvalidation

I want to have a custom validator for various fields that have specific validation rules, so I don't have to duplicate code. For this example, I want one for an email field. I have validation helper methods that will check basic stuff like if it is a valid email, but also perform some domain checks.

What I did first was having a `.NotNull()` rule on the field and then call my custom validator like so:

```
RuleFor(dto => dto.Upn).NotNull().EmailMustBeValid();
```

But this did not work. When the upn is null, it makes an error code for it, but still triggers my custom validator. The helper methods assume that the string is empty, not null. I can build in the checks for this, and I have. But I don't want to have two error codes that say the same thing because the email is null. I also don't want to forego the `.NotNull()` rule and put all the rules in my custom validator or helper methods.

What I tried next was this:

```
RuleFor(x => x.Upn).NotNull().NotEmpty().DependentRules(() => {
                RuleFor(x => x.Upn).EmailMustBeValid();
            });
```

This worked, but it harms the readability. I have also removed the `.WithMessage()` rules from this to make the example smaller. But all added together, it can get quite big.

I then tried to encapsulate all of this inside of my custom validator, but it seems I can't make use of dependent rules inside of custom validators? I seem to lose the parameter that is passed along. The code for my custom validator with dependent rules was:

```
public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, string> EmailMustBeValid<T>(this IRuleBuilder<T, string> ruleBuilder)
    {
        return ruleBuilder.NotNull()
            .DependentRules(() =>
            {
                ruleBuilder.Must(email => IsValidEmail(email));
            });
    }
```

When it gets to the method `IsValidEmail` the email parameter is still null but still the method gets called. So the dependent rule does not seem to work?

I also tried using the `When` condition, but these too don't seem to work inside of a Custom validator with the rulebuilder.

Am I correct in thinking that my only option is using the dependent rules on the validator itself, and having to repeat it wherever it is needed? I was hoping there was a proper way to encapsulate this logic inside of my custom validator.

The other solution that I see is to copy this logic into my `IsValidEmail` method and forego using rules like `NotNull()` and `NotEmpty()` but I am uncertain if this is the proper way to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, seems like I missed a part in the docs. I managed to fix it with Cascade mode altering.

My validator code now:

```
public TestValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(dto => dto.Upn).Cascade(CascadeMode.Stop)
            .NotNull().WithMessage("Not null triggered")
            .EmailMustBeValid();
    }
```

And my custom validator code:

```
public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, string> EmailMustBeValid<T>(this IRuleBuilder<T, string> ruleBuilder)
    {
        return ruleBuilder
            .Must(email => IsValidEmail(email))
            .WithMessage(ValidationErrorCode.UpnValidationFailed.ToString());
    }
```

This seems to be working fine, for some reason I could not get it to work with a class level Cascade mode, but this works for me.

I did get it to work by using `RuleLevelCascadeMode = CascadeMode.Stop;`